# what is the Best way UrlRewriting in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, umbraco7

**I want to change this**  http://localhost:65438/vehicle?id=12345
 **into**  http://localhost:65438/Make/Model/?id=12345

**For this i am using following code for urlrewriting in umbracoUrlRewriting.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlrewritingnet xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
  <rewrites>

    <add name="test"
virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)"
destinationUrl="~/vehicle?id="
rewriteUrlParameter="StoreInContextItems"
ignoreCase="true" />
  </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

**But the problem is that it is hitting the page load action of vehicle view continuously after a period of time without any request. 
Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: I would probably use the IIS URL Rewrite module instead (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)